# PHP empty() behaving strangely

Tags: php

I've come across an issue where on my local LAMP setup (running PHP 5.3), a test for an empty string using empty() works as expected, but the same site running on a remote server (PHP 5.1.6) is behaving differently, in that empty() isn't identifying empty strings. See below:

Form submits an empty text field value, php tests that it isn't empty using the following:

```
if ( ! empty($_POST['field'])
// On the remote server, the above condition never evaluates an empty field as empty. However, if i change this to the following, it works correctly..
if ($_POST['field'] !== '')
```

Anyone any clues why this might be happening?

Comment: What *does* it contain? Use `var_dump()` to find out.

Comment: var_dump contains: string(0) ""
true

Answer (score 4):

An empty string is not the only "empty" value. The value of `$_POST['field']` might very well be `null`, for example, which `!== ''`. See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php.

Comment: Hi, var_dump produces string(0) "" true. It's strange that I'm getting different behaviour for this locally and remotely...

Comment: Ok, that is really weird. What does `var_dump($_POST)` say?

Comment: Or $_POST['field'] could be 0. It will return false for "if (!empty($_POST['field']))" and true for "if ($_POST['field'] !== '')"

Answer (score 0):

`if ( ! empty($_POST['field'])`
It is in your code or only in the question? It should be:

```
if (!empty($_POST['field'])) {
    echo 'something';
}
```

Comment: Yes it's just for demonstrating the issue in the question, my code does a database insert if the value isn't empty